# Can't remove Philips 231P monitor SmartImage overlay

Tags: display, osd

I have a Philips Brilliance 231PQPYK IPS LED monitor connected to my desktop. It's worked fine for the past 2.5 years, but all of a sudden yesterday it gave me this strange SmartImage overlay with one side of the screen saying "SmartImage On" and the other saying "SmartImage Off" separate by a vertical line that moves back and forth across the screen. Here is a photo of it:
[image: Philips 231P SmartImage overlay]
The problem is, I can't find a way to turn off this overlay since none of the monitor's controls are responding! In fact I can't even turn the monitor off without unplugging the power. (this monitor is controlled by touch controls on the bottom right of the bezel as you can see in the photo)

Here's what I tried:

1. Changing the current DVI connection to VGA - no effect.
2. Unplugging the power overnight so maybe the monitor will reset, but that still didn't help.
3. Plugging in on the power and nothing else so the screen says "check connection". At this point the only OSD control I can bring up is the language selection, none of the other controls are working. But the SmartImage overlay doesn't appear.

This SmartImage overlay appears as soon as the computer is powered on and shows the BIOS screen. So I don't think this is a problem related to the operating system.

How do I fix this?? Thank you.

Comment: You need to locate it. Follow this screenshot or video to find the exit button - [exit SmartImage](https://puvox.software/blog/exit-smartimage-mode-philips-display/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out!! After some inquiries and a phone call, apparently all I have to do is press and hold the SmartImage button on the bottom of the bezel for *eight* seconds to turn off that overlay. This is not documented in the manual which is really annoying but glad it's fixed now!

Comment: My monitor was in this state for about a year so. You saved it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me. My 2 weeks old Philips 276E monitor has only a single button at the back. Holding it down for any amount of time did not remove the oscillating SmartImage demo line. A call to the dealer didn't help.

Just as it was looking hopeless, I remembered that I had downloaded the SmartControl software for the monitor. https://www.philips.co.in/c-p/203V5LSB26_94/lcd-monitor-with-smartcontrol-lite/support 
This software has a reset input. Using that feature did the trick. Hope this procedure is useful.