# Philips monitor smart image demo

Tags: display

I have an old Philips 220SW monitor that is permanently stuck in the SmartImage demo mode (there's a vertical line going back and forth across the screen). The SmartImage button on the front panel doesn't work. Is there any other way to turn this off? It's the same problem as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1237273/cant-remove-philips-231p-monitor-smartimage-overlay), except the button is broken for me.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Superuser.  Please take the tour at https://superuser.com/Tour to get the most out of this site.